# preg replace image link

Tags: php

I'm trying to preg_replace image link, but only if it ends with .jpg, .gif, .png.

```
 http://exampel.com/1/themes/b2/images/4/image1.jpg
```

to

```
<img src="http://exampel.com/1/themes/b2/images/4/image1.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6):

*Not sure it'll fully answer your question, but you should at least be able to use this as a basis...*

What about something like this :

```
$str = <<<TEST
here is
some text and an image http://exampel.com/1/themes/b2/images/4/image1.jpg ?
and some other http://exampel.com/1/themes/b2/images/4/image1.gif and
a link that should not be replaced : http://exampel.com/test.html !
TEST;

$output = preg_replace('#(http://([^\s]*)\.(jpg|gif|png))#', 
                '<img src="$1" alt="" width="" height="" />', $str);
var_dump($output);
```

Which gets me, for my example, the following output :

```
string 'here is
some text and an image <img src="http://exampel.com/1/themes/b2/images/4/image1.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" /> ?
and some other <img src="http://exampel.com/1/themes/b2/images/4/image1.gif" alt="" width="" height="" /> and
a link that should not be replaced : http://exampel.com/test.html !' (length=301)
```

The two images links have been replaced, and nothing else has been touched -- in particular, not the non-image link.

The regex I used matches :

- something that starts with `http://`
- contains anything that's not a white-character *(space, tabulation, newline)* : `[^\s]*`
- then, contains a dot : `\.`
- and, finally, one of the extensions you defined as corresponding to an image : `(jpg|gif|png)`

Then, all that matched string is injected into an `<img>` tag.